# О понятии "белый свет"

Tags: омонимы, фразеология

Интересно, как получилось, что словом "Свет" стали обозначать и оптическое явление, и мир. И почему "белый свет"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свет — освещение и свет — Земля, мир, вселенная -это омонимы, возникшие в результате распада многозначного слова ещё в древности. Этимологический анализ помогает установить их прежние семантические связи. Др.слав. слово означало "нечто противоположное понятию ТЬМА ", сияние, блеск.Впоследствии понятие ТЬМА вобрало в себя образ царства мёртвых, а ему противоположный образ-царство живых-"белый свет".Образ фразеологизма "белый свет" , таким образом, основан на архетипическом представлении о белом свете как об окружающем мире всех людей, вселенной; образ «будит» в сознании древнейшее, мифологическое, противопоставление света как жизни на земле – темному пространству за его пределами.